# Converting strings to IDateTime

Tags: r, data.table

I'm finding something weird when trying to convert some strings to IDateTime format. On February 12 at 4pm and later IDateTime computes the value for February 13.

```
> IDateTime(as.POSIXct('2006-02-12 15:59:57',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        idate    itime
1: 2006-02-12 15:59:57
> IDateTime(as.POSIXct('2006-02-12 16:00:00',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        idate    itime
1: 2006-02-13 16:00:00
> IDateTime(as.POSIXct('2006-02-12 22:00:00',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        idate    itime
1: 2006-02-13 22:00:00
```

The as.POSIXct seems to be working OK:

```
> as.POSIXct('2006-02-12 15:59:57',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
[1] "2006-02-12 15:59:57 PST"
> as.POSIXct('2006-02-12 16:00:00',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
[1] "2006-02-12 16:00:00 PST"
> as.POSIXct('2006-02-12 22:00:00',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
[1] "2006-02-12 22:00:00 PST"
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: there's nothing magic about Feb 12. I observe the same thing converting something like '2013-11-29'. The date increments by 1 after 16:00:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `?IDateTime` says:

> "ITime does not account for time zones."

Use `UTC` and everything will work, e.g.

```
IDateTime(as.POSIXct('2006-02-12 22:00:00',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz='UTC'))
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like it does assume local time, though, since I am 8 hours behind UTC.